# Doctrine 2 and SVN Externals

Tags: svn, doctrine-orm, svn-externals

Anybody know how to set up Doctrine 2 through SVN externals? I found [this project](http://code.google.com/p/doctrine2-svn/) but it seems to be outdated.

Comment: I also attempted to use http://svn.github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git but it failed with some PROPFIND error. I was able to checkout using that url, but the result was a strange directory structure that was missing most of the data.

Comment: Also, it would be nice if there was the ability to use a specific version (like 2.0.5)

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine 2 comes with 3 packages, in the [manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/introduction.html,%201.6.4%20Subversion) it says you will need to download Common and DBAL separately.

This is the [download page](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/download).